# Is it possible to reset the render view zoom level to 1:1?

Tags: image

After I have rendered an image I often want to zoom in and out to get a good look at it and check for problems etc. However, I don't know how to reset the zoom level back to 1:1 (1 image pixel = 1 display pixel). I know I can just save the render and look at it in an image viewing application, but I was wondering if there is a shortcut or toolbar button somewhere that will reset the zoom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to get a `1:1` zoom ratio in the Image editor. If you go to *View* in the header, you can see all the options there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to get into the habit of looking through the menus. Seems obvious now :)

Comment: in 2.8 it's in menu VIEW > FRACTIONAL ZOOM > ZOOM 1:1

Answer (score 4):

The relevant keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>1</kbd> for 1:1 zoom, <kbd>2</kbd> for 1:2, and <kbd>4</kbd> for 1:4.

Comment: Numbers on the numpad, not regular numbers.

Comment: these shortcuts can also be customized in  `User Preferences` > `Input` > `3D View` > `3D View (Global)` > `View Numpad` . So they can be anything you want. Useful for if you don't have a numpad or find laptop `fn` keys cumbersome.

Comment: Also compound with `Ctrl` for inverse.